# How do I import multiple EJB modules into a java ee project that can be accessed by the WAR controllers

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm creating a Java EE erp poject. It originally had one EJB module and worked fine for importing classes and entities alike. After having some issues with persistence units I decided to create another ejb module but I am unable to import any classes contained in that EJB module. 
I imported classes from the original ejb module like this:
import erp.production.entities.EntityName; 
When i attemp to do the same from the newly created ejb module it is unable to find the class.

Comment: cool, and what do you expect from us? To be clairvoyant? Star with reading [ask] and improve the question

Comment: I though this was a sufficient explanation of the problem and someone with experience would understand what I was asking. I solved my problem anyway. Solution: Right-click projectNode->properties->libraray->add the new ejb to same library as project. Solved

Comment: No, since this question is **not** java related, **nor** jsf, **nor** java-ee, but IDE related. And since you do **not** specify which IDE or if you are using maven or whatever, this question is not good... Please remove all these tags and add the tag of the IDE you are using